# How to access each index in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have

```
    <div class="star" index="1"></div>
    <div class="star" index="2"></div>
    <div class="star" index="3"></div>
      if(//the answer is true){
      $(".star").each(function(){
      $(this).index().addClass("active");
      index++;})
     }
```

i want to make star have class active one by one when the answer for each question is true and it's doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `attr('index')` instead of `index()`.Already is on loop so no need a `index++`

**For dynamic**

```js
function answer(ind){
  //if(validate answer true){
  $(".star[index='"+ind+"']").addClass('active')
  //}
}

answer(2)
```

```css
.active:before{
  content:'*'
}

.active{
 background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star" index="1">1</div>
<div class="star" index="2">2</div>
<div class="star" index="3">3</div>
```

Comment: can't, the class active will be add in 3 stars

Comment: i'll make its dynamic, when 2 i change with $this.starIndex(variable), the class active will be add in 3 stars

Comment: please be clear if you need a index of element or index attribute `index="number"`

Comment: can you provide any working example with your problem via snippet or fiddle?

Comment: i want to make star have class active one by one when the answer for each question is true and it's doesn't work

Comment: still you are not clear.i just create function for dynamic usage please check it

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to loop through all elements if you just want to add a class for the second element.

```js
$(".star[index='2']").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star" index="1">1</div>
<div class="star" index="2">2</div>
<div class="star" index="3">3</div>
```